# C++: define a function alias which is not a function pointer

Tags: c++, ld-preload

I want to write a small `LD_PRELOAD` library to intercept and log X11 calls (X11 is not significant here: choose any other library you'd like to log calls to). I would like to design a macro `GEN_WRAPPER` that automatically creates the wrapper for a certain call. This is my current attempt:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

#define GEN_WRAPPER(x)                                                  \
    template<typename Func>                                             \
    struct wrapper_ ## x;                                               \
    template<typename T, typename... S>                                 \
    struct wrapper_ ## x<T(S...)> {                                     \
        static T exec(S... s) {                                         \
            static decltype(x) *orig = reinterpret_cast<decltype(orig)>(dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, #x)); \
            std::cout << "Calling " #x;                                 \
            const auto ret = orig(std::move(s)...);                     \
            std::cout << " -> " << ret << std::endl;                    \
            return ret;                                                 \
        }                                                               \
    };                                                                  \
    decltype(x) *x ## _ptr = wrapper_ ## x<decltype(x)>::exec;
    /*decltype(x) x = wrapper_ ## x<decltype(x)>::exec;*/

GEN_WRAPPER(XOpenDisplay)
```

(ignore the problems related to perfect forwarding for this example, it is not the point)

If I call `GEN_WRAPPER(XOpenDisplay)`, the macro generates a variable called `XOpenDisplay_ptr` which is a pointer to a function with the same signature and return type as `XOpenDisplay`, but also has some simple logging code (which could be made more fancy, but this is not the point of the question either).

The problem is that `XOpenDisplay_ptr` is a pointer to a function, not a function. From the point of view of C++ code, this is nearly the same thing, but if I want to use this in a `LD_PRELOAD`-ed library I also need ABI compatibility, and of course the ABI is different between a function and a pointer to a function. What I would need is to define the function `XOpenDisplay` to be an alias of the static function `wrapper_XOpenDisplay<decltype(XOpenDisplay)>::exec` (which the macro already generates). Something like the commented line does, except the commented line is not valid C++.

Conceptually (at least for architecture x86_64), the thing the compiler has to do is very simple: it just has to generate the function `XOpenDisplay` with a simple `jmp` to the wrapper function (or copy its body). But I don't know how to express this in C++, if it's possible at all.

The only solution I know of is to explicitly write the function like this:

```cpp
Display *XOpenDisplay(const char *display_name) {
    return wrapper_XOpenDisplay<decltype(XOpenDisplay)>::exec(display_name);
}
```

But I cannot generate this inside the macro, because I cannot retrieve the arguments and return type.

Using C++20 is fine, as well as using GCC directives if required.

Comment: `The problem is that XOpenDisplay_ptr is a pointer to a function` Yes, so generally, your approach is just flawed and not the way to go. `because I cannot retrieve the arguments and return type.` So, is writing `GEN_WRAPPER(Display *, XOpenDisplay, const char *, display_name)` that much? It's not like the function is going to change. Writing a short parser for `/usr/include/X11/Xlib.h` to extract all function declarations and generating your wrappers shouldn't take that long.

Comment: Solving the practical problem is not difficult, of course. I am also asking to learn about the language.

Comment: Return type is not really problematic (some custom typetraits do the job), issue with arguments is to know the count at MACRO time (we know it at compile time only). KamilCuk proposed to pass extra types in `GEN_WRAPPER`, I have solution for `GEN_WRAPPER_1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For lack of a better answer, I came up with the following solution, which is compiler, architecture and ABI dependent, but gets the job done in my case.

```cpp
#if defined(__i386__)
#define JUMP_EAX "jmp *%eax"
#elif defined(__x86_64__)
#define JUMP_EAX "jmp *%rax"
#else
#error "Architecture unsupported"
#endif

#define GEN_WRAPPER(x)                                                  \
    namespace gio::wrapper {                                            \
    template<typename Func>                                             \
    struct wrapper_ ## x;                                               \
    template<typename T, typename... S>                                 \
    struct wrapper_ ## x<T(S...)> {                                     \
        static inline T exec(S... s) noexcept {                         \
            std::cout << "Backtrace for " #x << std::endl;              \
            backtrace();                                                \
            const static decltype(x) *orig = reinterpret_cast<decltype(orig)>(dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, #x)); \
            std::cout << #x "(";                                        \
            printer<S...>()(s...);                                      \
            std::cout << ")";                                           \
            std::cout.flush();                                          \
            const auto ret = orig(std::move(s)...);                     \
            std::cout << " = ";                                         \
            print_one<T>()(ret);                                        \
            std::cout << std::endl;                                     \
            return ret;                                                 \
        }                                                               \
    };                                                                  \
    __attribute__((unused)) static decltype(x) *__get_ ## x ## _ptr() asm("__get_" #x "_ptr"); \
    static decltype(x) *__get_ ## x ## _ptr() {                         \
        return &wrapper_ ## x<decltype(x)>::exec;                       \
    }                                                                   \
    __asm__ (".global " #x "\n"                                         \
             #x ":\n"                                                   \
             "call __get_" #x "_ptr\n"                                  \
             JUMP_EAX "\n");                                            \
    }
```